# Changing displayed columns or column titles for different (group) views?

Tags: list, list-view, column, groups

Is there a way to change the displayed columns or column titles when expanding/collapsing grouped items?

Example:
I have Hardware and Software products in my list.
For hardware I have specifications like: Dimension, Weight and Interfaces.
For software, these columns don't make sense so I'd like them to change to: OS, Version and Volume/Size.

So Either: 
Make 6 seperate columns with the values and show the relevant columns when expanding hardware or software. (if view = Hardware, then show column = A,B,C and hide = X,Y,Z)
Or: 
Have 3 columns with attributes and change the column title according to current view.
(if view = Hardware, then change column title attribute 1 to A, attribute 2 to B, attribut 3 to C)

I'm working on Sharepoint Server 2010.
Don't have SP-Designer at the moment, so a "Content Editor" solution would be amazing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I thik it will be better to create 6 independent columns, 2 content types in list:

1. hardware product - Dimension, Weight and Interfaces
2. software product - OS, Version and Volume/Size

And create 2 different views with columns for each product type.

All of this can be done in standard list settings.

Comment: That is a functioning option, but it gets rid of the rest of the items and makes in impossible to select and export items from different views.
Looks like I'll have to check with my boss and see what part of the user experience and useability is most important.
Thank you for your fast answer!